# Is there a way to tell which version of Team Foundation Server I'm connected to?

Tags: tfs

Is there a way, maybe in Visual Studio or from the command line, to figure out which version of TFS you're connected to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version can be requested by invoking the webservice on the TFS server if it is prior to TFS 2012:
http://tfsserver/VersionControl/v1.0/repository.asmx/GetRepositoryProperties

On TFS 2012 and later it does not return this information (or if it does, it's in an encrypted key).

this should give you enough info.

Comment: Is there a quick way I can invoke the web service without writing a program?

Comment: only if you have direct access to the server. the link can then be executed in a browser. otherwise, no...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "direct access." Like I'd have to remote into the server and open a browser there?

Comment: I don't have that sort of access to the server, so that won't work for me. Thanks, though.